# multiple CASE statements on interval within nested functions

Tags: matlab, switch-statement, case

Although I have come up with a work-around using  multiple `if / else if` statements, I am curious in knowing what looks wrong with my `case` statements, illustrated below:

```
function [ar_vo,bucket] = revEng(v)
...
s=solve(solve>0) * sqrt(T); 
ar_vo=s; 
bucket=ri(ar_vo);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function bucket = ri(ar_vo)
%          switch(ar_vo)
%              case ((ar_vo >= 0)&&(ar_vo < 0.005)) (1)
%                   bucket=1;
%              case ((ar_vo >= 0.005)&&(ar_vo < 0.02)) (2)
%                   bucket=2;
%              case ((ar_vo >= 0.02)&&(ar_vo < 0.05)) (3)
%                   bucket=3;
%              case ((ar_vo >= 0.05)&&(ar_vo < 0.1)) (4)
%                   bucket=4;
%              case ((ar_vo >= 0.1)&&(ar_vo < 0.15)) (5)
%                   bucket=5;
%              case ((ar_vol >= 0.15)&&(ar_vol < 0.25)) (6)
%                   bucket=6;
%              case (ar_vo >= 0.25)                     (7)
%                   bucket=7;
%              otherwise
%                   error('MATLAB:RI Bucket:NotAvailable.'); (8)
%          end
%
```

Given `ar_vo = 0.073...` while debugging the code, it skips `case (4)` for some reasons and reaches `case (8)`...

**Inefficient but working solution** with multiple `if / else if`:

```
    if ((ar_vo >= 0)&&(ar_vo < 0.005))
            bucket=1;
          else if ((ar_vo >= 0.005)&&(ar_vo < 0.02))
                 bucket=2;
              else if ((ar_vo >= 0.02)&&(ar_vo < 0.05))
                     bucket=3;
                  else if ((ar_vo >= 0.05)&&(ar_vo < 0.1))
                        bucket=4;
                      else if ((ar_vo >= 0.1)&&(ar_vo < 0.15))
                           bucket=5;
                          else if ((ar_vo >= 0.15)&&(ar_vo < 0.25))
                               bucket=6;
                              else if (ar_vo >= 0.25)
                                 bucket=7;
                                  else 
                                      error('MATLAB:RI Bucket:NotAvailable.');
                                  end
                              end
                          end
                      end
                  end
              end
          end
```

Comment: I many languages switch's cases require break; statement to indicate, that we do not want to fall through th rest of case statements but to finish switch. I do not know if this is the case

Comment: ok..., but certainly not in `matlab` as i sometimes use it without problem for other purposes than dealing with intervals (with `float` data types).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `case` expressions for your `switch` statement [*cannot* be conditionals](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) in MATLAB. They must be *values*.

```
switch thing
    case 1
        % do thing
    case {2, 3}
        % do other thing
    otherwise
end
```

So what MATLAB is doing in your case, is that it is converting your conditionals *into* values. So when you supply a value of 0.073 what MATLAB sees is this.

```
switch 0.73
    case 0
    case 0
    case 0
    case 1
    case 0
    case 0
    case 0
    otherwise
end
```

Since 0.73 obviously doesn't match any of those values you fall through to the `otherwise` and receive the error.

This is why switch statements are really only best for categorical data where you are comparing the input value against *exact* possible values (obviously not good for a floating point number).

### A crazy solution

If you **REALLY** want to keep this as a switch statement you *could* do a little trickery and actually make your switch expression simply "1" (`true`) and it will behave as you want it to.

```
switch(1)
    case ((ar_vo >= 0)&&(ar_vo < 0.005))
        bucket=1;
    case ((ar_vo >= 0.005)&&(ar_vo < 0.02))
        bucket=2;
    case ((ar_vo >= 0.02)&&(ar_vo < 0.05))
        bucket=3;
    case ((ar_vo >= 0.05)&&(ar_vo < 0.1))
        bucket=4;
    case ((ar_vo >= 0.1)&&(ar_vo < 0.15))
        bucket=5;
    case ((ar_vo >= 0.15)&&(ar_vo < 0.25))
        bucket=6;
    case (ar_vo >= 0.25)
        bucket=7;
    otherwise
        error('MATLAB:RI Bucket:NotAvailable.');
end
```

Please don't *actually* do this.

### A Real Solution

One sane approach is to use a series of [`if/elseif`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) statements (as opposed to your long tree of `if else if` statements). This is a good approach (and is well-suited to floating point numbers) as it simply checks if that number is within a given range.

```
if ((ar_vo >= 0)&&(ar_vo < 0.005))
    bucket=1;
elseif ((ar_vo >= 0.005)&&(ar_vo < 0.02))
    bucket=2;
elseif ((ar_vo >= 0.02)&&(ar_vo < 0.05))
    bucket=3;
elseif ((ar_vo >= 0.05)&&(ar_vo < 0.1))
    bucket=4;
elseif ((ar_vo >= 0.1)&&(ar_vo < 0.15))
    bucket=5;
elseif ((ar_vo >= 0.15)&&(ar_vo < 0.25))
    bucket=6;
elseif (ar_vo >= 0.25)
    bucket=7;
else 
    error('MATLAB:RI Bucket:NotAvailable.');
end
```

### The Best Solution

What I *personally* would do though, would be to remove all of that code and simply replace it with the following statements.

```
lowerlimits = [0, 0.005, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.25]
upperlimits = [lowerlimits(2:end), inf];

bucket = find(ar_vo >= lowerlimits & ar_vo < upperlimits);

if isempty(bucket)
    error('MATLAB:RI Bucket:NotAvailable.');
end
```

In this approach I compare `ar_vo` to all ranges *simultaneously* and then get the `bucket` value by using the index of the match. If there was no bucket assigned, there was no match, and `bucket` is an empty array.

This drastically reduces the chance of copy/paste errors and makes it easier if you want to modify the conditions at a later date. It is likely also more performant particularly for values > 0.25 which would have to traverse your entire `if/elseif` construct.

Comment: Astonished by the quality of your feedback. Thanks a lot for your explanation, as well as the `smart` feedback embodied by `The Best Solution`.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon [Suever's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35921078/3372061), and considering that you're actually trying to solve a data-binning problem, if you have **R2015a** or later, you can also use the built-in [`discretize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html) function to achieve the same thing; e.g.:

```
function bucket = ri(ar_vo,edgz)
  if nargin < 1
    edgz = [0, 0.005, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.25, inf];
  end
  bucket = discretize(ar_vo,edgz);
  if isnan(bucket)
      error('MATLAB:RI Bucket:NotAvailable.');
  end
end
```