# Switch-statement Matlab

Tags: matlab, switch-statement

I have the following set of `if` conditions:

```
If (0 <= x < 2)
 y=y1;
If (2 <= x < 5)
 y=y2;
If (5 <= x < Infinity)
 y=y3;
```

I need to code this using Switch Case in Matlab. Any idea ?

Comment: just add `swtich` and `end` at the beginning and end and lower case `If`? if you are not case matching, if matching should be the same as it is.

Comment: Why do you need to code this as a [`switch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) statement? An `if` statement seems more appropriate.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919254/multiple-case-statements-on-interval-within-nested-functions/35921078#35921078) as a reference for why switch/case is a bad use case here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual

> A *case_expression* cannot include relational operators such as < or > for comparison against the switch_expression. To test for inequality, use `if, elseif, else` statements

A switch case is best suitable for a small number of outcomes that are too tedious for if branching. If you really have to use `switch` then you need to
set an identifier which will define the case switch. Some examples are also [found in the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html)